# How to remove UINavigatonItem's border line

Tags: iphone, border, uinavigationitem

Is it possible to remove UINavigationItem's border? My view under black nav. bar is black and i don't want no visual border between them.

To make it clearer (image is not from my app):

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't *hide* it. You can add a subview that will *mask* it. Example:

```
UIView *overlayView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 43, 320, 1)];
[overlayView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[navBar addSubview:overlayView]; // navBar is your UINavigationBar instance
[overlayView release];
```

I didn't check it, but it should work.

---

**EDIT:** I checked it, it works.

Comment: If i understand you, this will add a view that will overlap with nav. item?

Comment: Yes. There is no other way to hide it. This "line" is part of the gradient.

Comment: No, wait.... It will add a subview which will "hide" the bottom line. Have you tried my method?

Comment: It's funny. Grey border remains in my app if i set color to black, but if i set color to white, then i get some kind of grey. I guess the view overlap and colors mix. Any trick so that colors of views wont mix?

Comment: It's strange... If you have UITableView in your view with _white_ backgroungColor, you should use _white_ color. Did you add some alphas there?

Comment: I have small view with black background (alpha=1) below nav bar and then below it tableview (alpha=1).

Comment: So you shoult "mask" it by using blackColor.

Comment: I am masking it with black color (image in the question is just for ilustration).

Comment: At last, i found my problem: Had to use CGRectMake(0, 42, 320, 1)], i guess my nav bar was shorter. Tnx for all the effort.

Answer (score 0):

in iOS6,you can hide it by set a clearColor Image to UINavigationBar's shadowImage.

check it here
[Remove the dark Line at the bottom of Navigationbar/Searchbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13745612/remove-the-dark-line-at-the-bottom-of-navigationbar-searchbar/20355827#20355827)