# Remove the dark Line at the bottom of Navigationbar/Searchbar

Tags: ios, xcode, uinavigationbar, uisearchbar

I want to make a clean white Design. So, I set the `tintColor` property to `whiteColor`, but there are these dark Lines under the `UINavigationBar` and `UISearchBar`.

Do some one know, how to remove the dark Lines or how to change the Color?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I did, and seemed to work, it is a further development of this link. I changed the explicit width declaration to a dynamic one, so that it will be the size of the view if you change view size or not:

```
UIView *overlayView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 43, self.view.frame.size.width, 1)];
[overlayView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[navBar addSubview:overlayView]; // navBar is your UINavigationBar instance
[overlayView release];
```

I found the stuff here:
[How to remove UINavigatonItem's border line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5888265/how-to-remove-uinavigatonitems-border-line)

Answer (score 3):

add a method to UIImage by category

```
+ (UIImage *)imageWithColor:(UIColor *)color {
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [color CGColor]);
    CGContextFillRect(context, rect);
    UIImage *theImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return theImage;
}
```

and just set

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setShadowImage:[UIImage imageWithColor:[UIColor whiteColor]]];
```

Comment: Or self.navigationController.navigationBar.shadowImage = [UIImage new];

Comment: @Caroline if in the storyboard,how to remove the navigationbar bottom line?

Answer (score 0):

From iOS 7 UINavigationBar has a shadowImage property that you can set to nil.