# Horizontal Separator NavBar IOS 7

Tags: uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, ios7

I have included the need for a navbar (navigationController) with the same tint of the background of the bar viewController ... Now I have a problem ... Between the navbar and the view I have a horizontal line that separates them, as you can see from the picture .. Can you tell me how can I delete this line horizontal black and make it more consistent?

I tried this in AppDelegate:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setShadowImage: [[UIImage alloc] init]];

     UINavigationController * nav = (UINavigationController *) self.window.rootViewController; nav.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
```

But I did not get results. Can you help? Thanks to all of Rory.

[image]

Comment: Please add picture in question which you mentioned.

Comment: May be the Image u are using have a black border, try making that border color as transparent.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You also have to set background image for navigation bar in order to achieve your requirement

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage alloc] init] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setShadowImage:[[UIImage alloc] init]];
```

Comment: Great, this makes things much more 'easy going to change the AppDelegate! Thank you very much!

Comment: Its not working work me. I tried by writing this code in Appdelegate as well as in my viewController also. I did'nt get it. Why its not working.

Comment: @ErAmitSachdeva I think you are also doing some another tricks also on Navigation bar. Otherwise it's working.

Answer (score 3):

You can hide it by using following code :

```
UIView *overlayView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 43, 320, 1)];
[overlayView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[navBar addSubview:overlayView]; // navBar is your UINavigationBar instance
[overlayView release];
```

Here is Ref : [How to remove UINavigatonItem's border line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5888265/how-to-remove-uinavigatonitems-border-line)

Comment: Divya works perfectly ... In a nutshell you create a view and soprappone the navbar right? All this should not even be "negative" in the eyes of the guidelines of apple right?

However Correct answer +1