# White line under UINavigationBar in IOS 7

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7, uikit

I have a `UITableViewController` with a `UISearchDisplayController` and `UISearchBar`.  I'm seeing a white line under the navbar when I present the view in a `UITabBarController`.  When I present the view modally in a `UINavigationController`, the line is either gray or black (I can't tell) and it looks perfectly normal.  Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem, couldn't figure out from where it did came from (it was present everywhere and it was NOT the `shadowImage`), ended up with the following fix (in my `UINavigationController` subclass)

```
// Fixes strange line under NavigationBar
{
    UIView * view = [[UIView alloc] init];
    view.backgroundColor = self.navigationBar.barTintColor;
    CGRect rect = view.frame;
    rect.origin.x = 0.f;
    rect.origin.y = self.navigationBar.frame.size.height;
    rect.size.width = self.navigationBar.frame.size.width;
    rect.size.height = 1.f;
    view.frame = rect;
    [self.navigationBar addSubview:view];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem too, after trying with a lot of methods,I find this way solved my problem

```
[[UISearchBar appearance] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yourColor]];
```

write it in your viewDidLoad.

Comment: Works for me in iOS 9, Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The white line is probably the [shadowImage](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationBar_Class/Reference/UINavigationBar.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationBar/shadowImage) of navigation bar.

Try setting it as:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.shadowImage = [UIImage new];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the clipsToBounds property on the UISearchBar to YES.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Use following line of the code :

```
UIView *overlayView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 43, 320, 1)];
[overlayView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];   // set color accordingly
[navBar addSubview:overlayView]; // navBar is your UINavigationBar instance
[overlayView release];
```

here is my posted Answer : 
[Horizontal Separator NavBar IOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19382235/horizontal-separator-navbar-ios-7/19382623#19382623)

[How to remove UINavigatonItem's border line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5888265/how-to-remove-uinavigatonitems-border-line)

Answer (score 0):

Swift version of Divya's answers

```
    let hideLineView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: navigationController!.navigationBar.frame.size.height, width: view.frame.size.width, height: 1))
    hideLineView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    navigationController!.navigationBar.addSubview(hideLineView)
```